# Expand a Richfaces collapsibleSubTable via javascript

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

How can I expand a `rich:collapsibleSubTable` with `expandMode="client"` via Javascript?

As I understood, the usual way to expand the subTable would be to either use the `expanded`-attribute

```
<rich:collapsibleSubTable 
      value="#{list.items}" 
      var="item" 
      expandMode="client" 
      expanded="true">
    <rich:column><h:outputText value="#{item.model}" /></rich:column>
</rich:collapsibleSubTable>
```

or use the `rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler`. But because we have the need to open every second sub-table on a datatable, I'm looking for a way to do that via javascript on client-side. Is there a way, to trigger the `expand` via the javascript RichFaces object or anything? Help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subTable has `collapse()` and `expand()` methods.

If you need to access all subtables you can do it with jQuery:

```
$('[id$=sbtbl]');
```

then as you go through the elements, the JS object that represents the table is:

```
element.rf.component; // element = $('[id$=sbtbl]')[n];
```

Comment: Awesome, basically `$('[id$=sbtbl]').each(function(n){this.rf.component.expand();});` works like a charme for all `collapsibleSubTable`, I'll go from here doing the filtering. Thnx @Makhiel